# exporting data from Bluemix Presence Insights

Tags: ibm-cloud, data-export, presenceinsights

I'm trying to export data from Presence Insights on Bluemix, I followed the following documentation:
https://presenceinsights.ng.bluemix.net/pidocs/analytics/export/
however I can't seem to find export button mentioned inside the document.

Answer (score 0):

Data can be exported from the IBM Presence Insights Dashboard if you have data available. There are also REST APIs for exporting data. They are documented in the Floors, Sites, and Zones sections of the [API Reference](https://presenceinsights.ibmcloud.com/pi-swagger/).

Answer (score 0):

There were REST APIs in the product some time ago, but they were found to have limitations that made them less useful in production.  In particular, the amount of data that builds up forces the response time on the API to grow beyond what the Bluemix infrastructure allowed.  The API requests would timeout.  To that end, the APIs were backed out, but it appears the documentation was left.  That will be removed shortly.

Presence Insights still understands the value of exporting the data, so a new scheme is under investigation.  For example, it would be ideal if the data could be exported under the covers to a production data storage facility, on a regular time frame.

In the interim, an alternative solution would be to use a Subscription to gather the backend enter/exit/dwell/timeout events directly and roll your own solution to store only what you need in whatever facility works for your application.